# Can't use CefSharp' IJsDialogHandler to catch the JavaScript alert event

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

I would like to catch the javascript alert event by IJsDialogHandler of CefSharp. But, I have four events of IJsDialogHandler listed as below:

```
    public void OnDialogClosed(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser)
    {
    }

    public bool OnJSBeforeUnload(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string message, bool isReload, IJsDialogCallback callback)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnJSDialog(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, string acceptLang, CefJsDialogType dialogType, string messageText, string defaultPromptText, IJsDialogCallback callback, ref bool suppressMessage)
    {
        if (Host != null)
        {
            Host.HandleDialog(messageText);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void OnResetDialogState(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser)
    {
    }
```

However, none of them can catch the Javascript alert event from the website.
For example: please visit this website and choose the follow conditions as below, you will see the javascript alert event.

Website is        http://www.travellers-autobarn.com.au/

Conditions are: (Pick up: Brisbane        Pick up date: 26/01/2016
                 Returning: Brisbane      Returning date: 04/02/2016)

Really appreciate if someone who can figure it out, I have tried several ways to catch this Javascript alert event, but still got nothing.

Comment: What happens when you enter the provided steps in `Chrome`? For me it opens a new window. If I pick a journey shorter than `10 days` then `OnJsDialog` is called as expected. Also please have another read over https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/45/CefSharp/IJsDialogHandler.cs#L22, if you are implementing a custom dialog at some point you will need to execute the `IJsDialogCallback`

Comment: Yep, you are right. This web does not allow customers to choose duration less than 10 days. This is not a custom dialog, but it is a javascript alert. I would like to use cefsharp to close it, but dont know how

Comment: Take a closer look at the documentation link I sent, there is a `suppressMessage` param.....

Comment: Cool, I will try to set supperssMessage to true, and see what's going on.

Comment: What is the cef version?